# can we expand the relation between the determinant of a transformation and area of parallelogram to farther dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, matrix-equations

I'm now trying to understand determinants of linear transformations, and I was introduced to **determinants** as (*the scaling factor that we multiply it by any area to figure out what the area of the image of the first area is going to be under a transformation*), and I was told that the same thing goes when dealing with 3-dimensional transformations (but this time with volumes). So my question is **can we extend that relation between determinants and shapes to further (4,5,6,...,etc.) dimensions?** and, if we can, then **how can we relate the formula of $n \times n$ matrices’ determinants**
$$\det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\det(A_{ij})$$(where $j$ is the column (unfixed) and $i$ is the row (fixed) and $A_{ij}$ is the $n-1 \times n-1$ matrix that remains after removing the $i^{th}$ row and the $j^{th}$ column)?

Comment: Yes, the analogy works in any dimension. But what is “the equation of determinants”?

Comment: oh sorry i've edited the question and added the formula

Comment: OK, that is one of the formulas to compute a determinant. Are you looking for a geometric interpretation of this particular formula?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Some related questions whose answers may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577781, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211087, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034864, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630257. A way to relate those answers to your formula would be to see how your formula relates to the other definitions of the determinant.